# iOS: Using Location Services to Block Content and Handling App Submission

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning

The app we are working on uses location services to block content if you are not located in a specific area. Since this area is not the USA, when the app is submitted, content will be blocked. What is the recommended approach for submitting the app so that the content will not be blocked.

Do the Apple testers have a tool to mimic different regions for Location Services and we just need to add notes surrounding this?

OR

Should we to use a remote configuration file that could be used to toggle the acceptable locations while the app goes through the submission process?

Answer (score 1):

Since even the iOS simulator supports setting custom geolocations, I would just use the notes to add instructions for the testing location.

Comment: Thanks, have you done this before? I can't afford for the app to be rejected.

Comment: No, I didn't, sorry. But I don't think you need to be worried, this seems to be quite common.